# concatenation in sql not working as expected

Tags: mysql, sql, concatenation

I am tring to execute the below code...

```
select a.name, a.phone, b.mobile, b.relation,
case
  when a.phone<>'' and b.mobile<>'' then a.phone + ' ' + b.mobile
  when a.phone<>'' and b.mobile='' then a.phone
  when a.phone='' and b.mobile<>'' then b.mobile
else ''
end as phone
from abc a join bcdb where a.id=b.id and b.relation='a123'
```

but on executing the first case, the values are summed up instead of being concatenated... can you please guide me

Comment: i get error when i use two pipe symbol (||)..

Comment: What data types are the columns and what is your RDBMS - SQL Server , MySQL?

Comment: Post the error that you're receiving in your question.

Comment: You version of sql server?

Comment: You have to cast or convert numerical (int, bigint, etc) values if you want to concatenate them with strings: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa276862%28v=sql.80%29.aspx

Comment: apply a convert function before concatenate fields.

Comment: these fields are varchar in type... yet i get the values summed up... db - mysql

Comment: Using MySQL you've got to concatenate your strings with the [CONCAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using MySQL, you've got to use the [CONCAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) function to concatenate your strings, not the `+` operator.

```
select a.name, a.phone, b.mobile, b.relation,
case
    when a.phone<>'' and b.mobile<>'' then CONCAT(a.phone, ' ',  b.mobile)
    when a.phone<>'' and b.mobile='' then a.phone
    when a.phone='' and b.mobile<>'' then b.mobile
    else ''
end as phone
from abc a join bcdb where a.id=b.id and b.relation='a123'
```

Remark: You should take care that none of the operands should be NULL.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED**:
You seem to be storing phone and mobile columns as numbers. SO you'll have to convert them to strings for concatenation. Try this:

```
CONVERT(a.phone, CHAR) + ' ' + CONVERT(b.mobile, CHAR)
```

So your query effectively becomes this:

```
select a.name, a.phone, b.mobile, b.relation,
case
  when a.phone<>'' and b.mobile<>'' then CONVERT(a.phone, CHAR) + ' ' + CONVERT(b.mobile, CHAR)
  when a.phone<>'' and b.mobile='' then a.phone
  when a.phone='' and b.mobile<>'' then b.mobile
else ''
end as phone
from abc a join bcdb where a.id=b.id and b.relation='a123'
```

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: i get the error - #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'a.phone) + ' ' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(30), b.mobile) when a.phone<>'' and b.mobile='' at line 3

Comment: @SamuelMathews I've updated my answer. Take a look at it

Comment: the values stil gets added.. rather than being concatenated  :(

Answer (score 0):

The phone number must be stored as a number instead of a string.

Use your database platforms convert function.

Example:

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), a.phone) + " " + CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), b.mobile)
```

Since we now know this is MySql, you can try:

```
CONCAT(a.phone, " ", b.mobile)
```

Comment: they are stored as varchar

Comment: They are being summed as numbers.  Are you sure they are stored as varchars?

Answer (score -1):

I believe your database is automatically converting your phone columns to integer values, and that's why its adding them instead of concatenating.

Try forcing convert the phone columns to varchar datatype. Since I don't know what database you're using, I'll give an example that would work on SQL Server.

[edit]
Since you're using MySQL, you have to use the CAST() function, instead of the CONVERT() function.
The CONVERT() function in MySQL is used to convert encoding.
Check the documentation at: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-convert.html
[/edit]

```
select a.name, a.phone, b.mobile, b.relation,
case
  when a.phone<>'' and b.mobile<>'' then CAST(a.phone as VARCHAR(50)) + ' ' + CAST(b.mobile AS VARCHAR(50))
  when a.phone<>'' and b.mobile='' then a.phone
  when a.phone='' and b.mobile<>'' then b.mobile
else ''
end as phone
from abc a join bcdb where a.id=b.id and b.relation='a123'
```

Comment: i get this error 
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'VARCHAR, a.phone) + ' ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, b.mobile) when a.phone<>'' and b.mo' at line 3

Comment: Now that I know you're using MySQL I was able to edit my answer according to the database. Please check again.